# How to speed-up Python PIL image filtering function

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have two grayscale pngs. These images have the same width and height.

For example:

[image: image1] 
[image: image2]

I need to filter these images in the following way: when a pixel from image1 has a value different from 255 and the pixel in the same position has a value different from 255 I want to store both pixels in two separate images (imageFiltered1 and imageFiltered2). Then both filtered images will create a new image thanks to multiply from ImageChops.

This is the algorithm I pulled together:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PIL import Image, ImageChops

def makeCustomMultiply(image1, image2):
    assert image1.size == image2.size

    imageFiltered1 = Image.new(size=image1.size, mode='L', color=255)
    imageFiltered2 = Image.new(size=image1.size, mode='L', color=255)

    for eachY in xrange(0, imageFiltered1.size[1]):
        for eachX in xrange(0, imageFiltered1.size[0]):
            pixel1 = image1.getpixel((eachX, eachY))
            pixel2 = image2.getpixel((eachX, eachY))

            if pixel1 == 255 or pixel2 == 255:
                imageFiltered1.putpixel((eachX, eachY), 255)
                imageFiltered2.putpixel((eachX, eachY), 255)
            else:
                imageFiltered1.putpixel((eachX, eachY), pixel1)
                imageFiltered2.putpixel((eachX, eachY), pixel2)

    combo = ImageChops.multiply(imageFiltered1, imageFiltered2)
    return combo

if __name__ == '__main__':

    image1 = Image.open('image1.png')
    image2 = Image.open('image2.png')

    myCustomMultiply = makeCustomMultiply(image1, image2)
    myCustomMultiply.save('myCustomMultiply.png')
```

It is basically a multiply function where black/gray against white is not showed. Only gray to gray is then multiplied.

Can my code be improved somehow?
I would like to avoid the nested for loops which slow down my code quite a lot. This function has to be used hundreds of times each time I run my program.

Thanks

ouput :

[image]

Comment: this is the output of my function: <https://i.stack.imgur.com/NN7Bq.png>

Comment: you may want to check [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

This can be improved a lot by using array-wise operations instead of for-loops. Replace the for-loops by this code:

```
import numpy as np

# convert to numpy arrays
image1_array = np.array(image1)
image2_array = np.array(image2)

# find all pixels where your condition is fulfilled:
condition = (image1_array == 255) | (image2_array == 255)

# If the condition is fulfilled, set 255, else set the original value
imageFiltered1_array = np.where(condition, 255, image1_array)
imageFiltered2_array = np.where(condition, 255, image2_array)

# convert back to PIL images. 
imageFiltered1 = Image.fromarray(imageFiltered1_array)
imageFiltered2 = Image.fromarray(imageFiltered2_array)
```

If you want even further speedups, you can look into using torch instead of numpy for the numerical operations, it is even faster in some cases.